# Cannot use repository inside custom request class for request validations in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-validation

So I am trying to validate `email` and `name` in `UserCreateRequest` class but `@Wired` doesn't work and `userRepository` is null

##### UserCreateRequest.java:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class UserCreateRequest {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserCreateRequest() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserCreateRequest(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Name should be between 2 and 20 characters")
    private String name;


    @NotBlank(message = "Email is mandatory")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Date of birth is mandatory")
    @DateFormatRule(message = "Date of birth should be in yyyy-MM-dd format")
    private String dob;

    public User validated() {
        if (userRepository.findUserByEmail(email).isPresent()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Email already exists");
        }
        if (userRepository.findUserByName(name).isPresent()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Name already exists");
        }


        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setDob(LocalDate.parse(dob));

        return user;
    }
}
```

##### UserController.java:

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserCreateRequest userCreateRequest) {

    User validatedData = userCreateRequest.validated();

    User createdUser = this.userService.addUser(validatedData);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(createdUser);
}
```

Error I am getting when sending request:

```
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n",
    "message": "Cannot invoke \"com.test.restapi.repository.UserRepository.findUserByEmail(String)\" because \"this.userRepository\" is null",
    "path": "/api/students"
```

I want to check database if user `name` or `email` already exists from the request class, without checking that from controller.

is there any way to use `userRepository` in `UserCreateRequest` class like that?

I could not find the exact solution I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserCreateRequest` is not a spring-managed component, it's created by mapping request payload to the class. You can:

1. Autowire repository manually by injecting the context in the controller - just don't do that, you are already mixing responsibilities by adding business logic (validation and mapping) to the dto.
2. Create validation annotations to apply on the fields - `@UniqueName`, `@UniqueEmail`. Their validators can be easily made into spring-managed components.

Comment: Thanks. I have just started learning Spring Boot. Do you have any suggestions for resources where I can see how that kind of stuff is managed in a clean way and what are the best practices, without writing everything in one place so the code can be easily readable?

Comment: @b.tsutskiridze Try to adhere to the single responsibility principle. In the current context, use custom validation annotations - [just one possible guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator), use a mapper to transform dto to entity - [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) is about model mapper, but there are other libraries (or you can write your own mapper, if you don't need all the functionalities provided by those libraries).

Comment: And I would also add, stop using Lombok, it's fine for a school project but debugging under the hood generated code is a pain and I don't wish that on anyone who will maintain your code when working in a team for a project in a company. [Here is a bigger read on the subject](https://medium.com/@vgonzalo/dont-use-lombok-672418daa819).